# Where is the Google App Engine SDK path on OSX?

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

I need to know for creating a Pydev Google App Engine Project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`/usr/local/google_appengine` - that's a symlink that links to the SDK.

Comment: ...if you tell the Launcher to make the symlinks.

Comment: Mine actually didn't link the directory at all. In /usr/local/bin it linked to all of the .py files in the SDK. I'm using the latest app engine on OSX 10.10

Comment: found mine in: `/Users/username/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine` (OSX 10.13.3, Google Cloud SDK 189.0.0)

Answer (score 28):

> `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine`

Comment: If you just updated the SDK, the google_appengine dir does not exist, there is just the zipped file. You have to launch Google App Engine client to unzip it and create symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

**For MAC OS**

Instead of installing from the cloud.google website, install the sdk with brew

```
brew cask install google-cloud-sdk
```

After that install the python componenents :

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
```

In pycharm set the path to :

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
```

This might be different for different users but make sure to select the google_appengine from the platform folder and it should work like a charm

Comment: `gcloud components install app-engine-python` was the trick for me, thanks

I had previously installed from the cloud.google website into my home directory so I didn't try the brew cask, but in this case the path to use in pycharm was `~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`